# C# WinForms contextmenu focus issue when textbox is added

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, contextmenu

In a C# WinForms application I need to create a `ContextMenuStrip` with dropdown and textbox:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip ct1;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var header = new ToolStripMenuItem("Header");
    header.Enabled = false;

    var options = new ToolStripMenuItem("Options");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var checkoption = new ToolStripMenuItem("Check Me " + i + "!");
        checkoption.CheckOnClick = true;
        options.DropDownItems.Add(checkoption);
    }

    var txt = new ToolStripTextBox();
    txt.Text = "changeme";


    options.DropDownItems.Add(txt);

    options.DropDown.Closing += DropDown_Closing;

    ct1.Items.Clear();
    ct1.Items.Add(header);
    ct1.Items.Add(options);

    ct1.Show(this, button.Left, button.Top);
}

private void DropDown_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked);
}
```

Now, `e.Cancel` will prevent closing the dropdown if the reason is `ItemClicked`, so I can select more items without having to open the menu again:

[image]

Please note that "changeme" is a `ToolStripTextBox`!

Once I focus it (click on it), I can edit the text inside:

[image]

After finish editing the textbox, I still can change the checkbox items, but there is **no focus indicator**:

[image]

How can I get back the focus indicator just as shown on the first picure?

Note: if I move the mouse onto "Header", the dropdown will close, and then moving it back to "Options", will reopen the dropdown and then the focus indicator is good again:

[image]

How can I do this without closing and reopening the dropdown?

I have tried `Select()` for the `options` item, but it did not help, neither `Invalidate()` on `ct1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just have found it:

First needs to add a click handler on the dropdown:

```
options.DropDown.Click += DropDown_Click;
```

Then in the click handler it needs to be focused:

```
private void DropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropdown = (ToolStripDropDown)sender;
    dropdown.Focus();
}
```

Comment: However this is not perfect, because the first click after editing the textbox will also change the checked state of the clicked item. I wanted to *exit* from the editing mode and get back the focus. Then the next click can change the state.